# MATLAB - Get a list of the current set of datatips

Tags: matlab

I have a figure with several plots. Each plot is from a subset of an original data set. I have custom datatips and each datatip includes the index from the original data set for each selected point.

What I'm trying to do is get access to the current collection of datatips in that figure so I can see what all of the index values are. (From there, I have more involved data processing of the original data set, but I just need to get through this question.)

I have a custom button on the figure with a working callback (that doesn't do anything yet), so I should have access to the figure (parent of the button) and all of the contents of the figure. But I can't track down where the datatip collection is located. I'm assuming I'll find a cell array of individual datatips, and I should be able to extract the information I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

After a little rooting around the existing datatip code, here is what I came up with. The key was getting the handles for the datatip structures via the *datacursormode()* and *getcursorInfo()* functions.

Each plotted line is of a subset of data vectors that are from an original dataset. If you have a custom datatip, you have access to the index of the data used for the plot. This is not the same as the index in the original dataset. So some precalculated mapping is used to obtain the original index from the datatip index. That mapping is not shown here, but it was included in the UserData property of the line plot. (This requires some coding on the user's part.)

```
function getDataTipsData(src,event)    
% Several plots are on a figure. 
% The button that was pushed is a child of the figure (by design).
% src is the handle of the button.
% src.Parent is the figure handle
p = src.Parent;

% Obtain a structure that contains the datatip information using these steps
dcm = datacursormode(p);
info_dcm = getCursorInfo(dcm);

% The button may have user data attached to it as part of its instantiation
% and configuration
plotTitle = src.UserData.plotTitle;

% Allocate an array
some_user_data_from_each_datatip = zeros(1,numel(info_dcm));

% Iterate through the datatips and extract the data from each one
if ~isempty(info_dcm)
    for i = 1:numel(info_dcm)
        % Get the index into the array that the datatip is referencing.
        % Sinde there may be moultiple plots on the figure, this index 
        % is specific to the x,y (and z) data of the line this datatip
        % is referencing.
        idx_subset = info_dcm(i).DataIndex;

        % Target is the line object that ther datatip is referencing. It
        % has pre-established user data, that was added to the plot when
        % it was originally plotted.        
        tgt_data   = info_dcm(i).Target.UserData;

        % ioi is a vector of indices of interest, which maps the index within the 
        % data used for this line into the index of the original dataset.
        idx_original = tgt_data.ioi(idx_subset);
        some_user_data_from_each_datatip(i) = tgt_data.some_field(idx_original);
    end
end
```